# Adjoint action of Lusztig's integral form preserves the De Concini-Kac integral form: reference?

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

Let $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ be the quantized enveloping algebra of a complex semisimple Lie algebra. I have seen in several papers the following fact stated: the adjoint action of Lusztig's integral form (with divided powers) of $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ on itself preserves the De Concini-Kac integral form (without divided powers). Does anyone know a reference for this fact? I haven't found it in any books.